# how to store and filter results returned by google places api

Tags: android

i have developed an app using Google places API.. I have set query to search for "electronic stores" ranked by distance. I want to cache the results returned by Google places API since i want to perform some operations like filtering the result. For eg: currently my app makes a call to list the nearest "cafe" from the user. Now if i want to filter the result such a way that it will only show "starbucks" and no other cafe, how do i go about it? How do i cache this info returned by api?

here is a small part from my logcat. when the result is returned and i click on starbucks, this is what i get. of this the only info that i want to cache is the name of cafe and its latitude longitude values.

02-09 15:48:58.728: D/Place(6960): Starbucks300  United States 32.731918-97.111658

Answer (score 0):

insert the results into a SQLite database, it'll also make searching, filter and sorting easier and faster with SQL queries.

Comment: thanks Gal .. but what i don't know is how do i catch the result returned by Google places.. my thinking is, there will b 3 layers.. the bottom most layer is result returned by google. next layer where i will perform the filter and the third layer wherein i will perform operations on filtered data.. i would like to know how do i catch the data returned by google.

Comment: Create a class for a single Place, then hold the data returned from the API in an ArrayList<Place>, create a new ArrayList<Place> for each of your operations and keep the previous one as 'cache'